# Launching Spark on EC2 - SSH return code 255

Tags: apache-spark, ec2-ami

I've been creating spark clusters on ec2 since last week, which were launching fine until a couple of days back. Since Monday though, every single time i try to launch it i get the same error

```
Warning: SSH connection error. (This could be temporary.)
Host: ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
SSH return code: 255
SSH output: Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com,a.b.c.d' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have seen similar questions asked on the site [EC2-SSH error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36403951/spark-ec2-ssh-connection-error-ssh-return-code-255)  , but haven't come across a resolution that has worked for Spark 1.6.1.  I have tried waiting for it to resolve itself (as suggested in other answers) , but that hasn't worked.

Could some throw some light on what the issue could be.  Thanks in advance !

Comment: is the SSH error occurring between you and the driver node? or is it occurring between the driver and other executor nodes?

Comment: It's happening between me and the driver node. I've tried to ping the IPs for both master and slave too , and that times out as well.